# Capitalize First Letter of Every Word inside Bracket

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write some useful Regex for Tagscanner (a music tagger on Windows) and spent a bunch of time on regex101.com to fulfill my idea.

In some language like French, it's a huge pain to make the title look good if you capitalize every word. I just want to capitalize the first letter of every word in round bracket. I will receive the string like this :

Edith Piaf - La vie en rose (louis armstrong 2015 version)

I started with this base :

```
/([a-z])([\w-']*)([\s\)\]\,;\d]*|$)/gi
that I replace by \U\1\E\2\3

([a-z]) I try to capture the letter I want in uppercase
([\w-']*) What I expect to be the rest of the word
([\s\)\]\,;\d]|$) Delimiters
```

This will actually Capitalize everywhere correctly in the title, then the problems come...

I tried to ignore everything until I encounter '('

```
\(\K or \({1} or with \(\A or \((*SKIP) etc...
```

Positive lookbehind (?<=() doesn't work either because after my first match
it will look if I have '(' again.

Also tried to capture the whole thing and put * after doesn't work either.

I just don't know how to do it. Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/T1hJKz/2. Or https://regex101.com/r/T1hJKz/3

Comment: Hello @WiktorStribiżew thank you for your fast reply. It work like a charm on regex101.com . But my soft doesn't like it...

The result giving me : 
La vie en rose (\Ul\Eouis \Ua\Ermstrong 2015 \Uv\Eersion)

I will study your code! It's a big improve in my comprehension.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The soft doesn't support the \U\E It's time for changing for one that can. Thanks a lot anyway!!!

Comment: Please update the question when you decide what environment you chose and let know via a comment.

Answer (score 0):

With Perl's rename from @Wiktor Stribiżew's regex:

```
rename -n 's/(?:\G(?!^)|\()[^()]*?\K\b(\p{Ll})(\w*)/\U$1\E$2/gmu'  Edith*
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good.

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

[cpan standalone script](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625192518/https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)